# Is it possible to use JAXB to map from schema to a java.util.Map?

Tags: java, schema, xsd, jaxb

I have an existing XML schema that contains a type that I would like to map to a Java Map of some sort using JAXB. My build process takes the schema and creates the beans. I would like to customize this process by having one of the complexTypes in my schema map to a java.util.Map. I've read somewhere that JAXB "can't do interfaces." I'm not sure if that applies in this case, but if so I'd be fine with it mapping to a HashMap. Also, it doesn't necessarily have to be the complexType that maps to a Map, it could be an element if that's what's required.

I control my JAXB generation using a .xjb file, so I'm looking for some `<jaxb:bindings>` to put in there. I've tried the following, but it does not work:

```
<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="myschema.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
    <jaxb:globalBindings>
        <jaxb:serializable uid="1"/>
    </jaxb:globalBindings>
    <jaxb:schemaBindings>
        <jaxb:package name="com.myschema.client.types"/>
    </jaxb:schemaBindings>
    <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='MapType']">
            <jaxb:javaType name="java.util.HashMap"
            parseMethod="com.myschema.common.MapConverter.parseObjectToMap"
            printMethod="com.myschema.common.MapConverter.printMapToObject" />
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

**Edit:** I've added more detail on the above binding that I've already tried. It generates the following error during schema compile:

```
[jaxb] [ERROR] compiler was unable to honor this javaType customization. It is attached to a wrong place, or its inconsistent with other bindings.
```

---

`<jaxb:javaType>` will not work because it can only be used for [mapping between XML Schema primitives and Java types](http://fusesource.com/docs/framework/2.2/jaxws/JAXWSCustomTypeMappingJavaType.html). Since I want to map between a complex type and a Java type, I cannot use this.

Comment: Your `.xjb` approach is the correct one, and should work. Does XJC just ignore it, or does it generate the wrong thing?

Comment: Using the above .xjb approach, I get the following error in my jaxb compile:

    [jaxb] [ERROR] compiler was unable to honor this javaType customization. It is attached to a wrong place, or its inconsistent with other bindings.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your XJC file is using the "standard" `javaType` directive, which I believe is limited to converting String values to and from a representative java type. As such, it's only suitable for converting simple element and attribute content.

The XJC tool provides an enhanced version of `javaType`, which in theory should be able to handle more complex structures.  Unfortunately, this has yet to be implemented:

https://java.net/jira/browse/JAXB-209 (unresolved)

> For instance, being able to map a
>   schema type to a HashMap might  be a
>   likely requirement for those using
>   model driven design/implementation. 
>   AFAICS, this is not possible today. 
>   Therefore, one must manually edit the 
>   generated code.

Looks like you're out of luck.

Comment: I was hoping this wouldn't be the answer, but I'm glad to know I'm not missing anything.

Comment: Just to point out this new PR which will solve the initial demand : https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jaxb-ri/pull/1781

Answer (score 6):

Have you looked at example here (Customized mapping of HashMap):
http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlAdapter.html

Need to create custom XmlAdapter I'm afraid.

Comment: Hey, this looks pretty close to what I want to do! The only thing is, I'm using schema to generate Java types (as part of my build process). I don't mind writing the adapter, but I would like to avoid having to have pre-implemented the class that generates the schema (<code>MyHashMapType</code> and <code>MyHashMapEntryType</code> in the linked example) as this is going backwards for me. Is this possible?

Comment: I don't think this strictly necessary, most likely it's just extended example. I know that we have done it in the past with just schema, binding customization file and adapter.

Comment: An `XmlAdapter` is what XJC should be generating using @Zach's `.xjb` configuration.

Comment: Try `<xjc:javaType />`, see [http://jaxb.java.net/2.1.2/docs/vendorCustomizations.html#javaType]

Answer (score 0):

Very old question but new answer possible when this [PR](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jaxb-ri/pull/1781) will be merged.

With this new PR, `xjc:javaType` will now handle generic types.

It has been tested with jaxb-tools' maven-plugin with the following example syntax :

```xml
<jaxb:bindings node=".//xsd:attribute[@name='subRatings']">
  <jaxb:property>
    <jaxb:baseType>
      <xjc:javaType name="java.util.List&lt;java.lang.String&gt;" adapter="org.jvnet.jaxb.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.CommaDelimitedStringAdapter"/>
    </jaxb:baseType>
  </jaxb:property>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

The generated java class property looks like below with no more `import java.util.List<String>;` erroneous import

```java
@XmlAttribute(name = "subRatings")
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CommaDelimitedStringAdapter.class)
protected List<String> subRatings;
```

It fixes the [#209](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jaxb-ri/issues/209) and [#737](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jaxb-ri/issues/737) issues in jaxb-ri repository