# JAXB substitution of complex type with primitive type

Tags: java, jaxb

In my schema I have some types that simply extend a simple XSD type (int or string). JAXB creates a separate java class per such type. I want to drop this intermediate class and configure JAXB to use primitives where possible (e.g. substitute `CountryType` with `java.lang.String` and `DocumentType` with `int` or `lava.lang.Integer`). For example, for a given XSD it would be nice to have `DestinationType.setDocumentType(int)` and `List<String> StatesType.getCountry()`. I am happy to write type-wide [an adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881712/is-it-possible-to-use-jaxb-to-map-from-schema-to-a-java-util-map) for that, but it looks like only conversions from primitive XML types are supported. Maybe it is possible to make per-property type conversion? Please, give any example of JAXB binding customization, that can help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:exch="http://www.mycompany.org/exchange"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    targetNamespace="http://www.mycompany.org/exchange"
    elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

    <complexType name="countryType">
        <simpleContent>
            <extension base="string"/>
        </simpleContent>
    </complexType>

    <complexType name="statesType">
        <sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <element name="country" type="exch:countryType"/>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>

    <complexType name="documentType">
        <simpleContent>
            <extension base="integer"/>
        </simpleContent>
    </complexType>

    <complexType name="destinationType">
        <sequence>
            <element name="states" type="exch:statesType" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <element name="document-type" type="exch:documentType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
</schema>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possibility, can you change your schema?:

The following schema change will generate your desired object model.

Use:

```
<simpleType name="documentType">
    <restriction base="integer"/>
</simpleType>
```

Instead of:

```
<complexType name="documentType"> 
    <simpleContent> 
        <extension base="integer"/> 
    </simpleContent> 
</complexType>
```

Comment: Can this transformation be applied without breaking the compatibility of serialized XML?

Comment: @dma_k - Yes, the XML representations for both types is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Good question. In the past I've solved this by running the schema through an XSLT pre-processing step, "flattening" the type hierarchy whilst retaining the semantics of the documents.

For example, the XSLT would drop the definition of the `documentType` type, and replace every reference to `documentType` with `integer`. The resulting processed schema still represents the same instance documents, but is simpler, and makes for a nicer binding.

This (rather half-baked) solution can apply to a number of similar problems to do with over-complex schema (e.g. replacing substitution groups with choice structures).