# XJC javaType adapter in complexType

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd, xjc

I want to get XJC to use the javaType tag in a complexType when generation beans. Is this not allowed? I'm really missing good documentation and some understandable error message.

Here is what I am trying which fails with the errors:

- compiler was unable to honor this conversion customization. It is attached to a wrong place, or its inconsistent with other bindings.
- (the above customization is attached to the following location in the schema)

Here is the XSD:

```
<xs:complexType name="MyMap">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:appinfo>
      <xjc:javaType name="my.company.HashMapHidingGenerics" adapter="my.company.adapter.MyMapAdapter" />
    </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="entry" type="MyEntry"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="MyEntry">
  <xs:attribute name="someAttribute" use="optional"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bad news: `<javaType>` only supports simple types (see  [Binding Declarations](http://www.huihoo.org/openweb/java_web_services_tutorial/JAXBusing4.html#wp148613) and [Is it possible to use JAXB to map from schema to a java.util.Map?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1889584/267197)).

However you can achieve what you need by using [`@XmlAdapter`](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xmladapter-jaxbs-secret-weapon.html).

Comment: That's bad :-( The problem with using only XmlAdapter is that I will have to generate extra classes that inherit from the auto generated code and then still add an extra object factory. This <javaType> annotation would save me all this hassle.